# How to run Cpanel node js even on server restart

Tags: javascript, node.js, cpanel, pm2

I built a Nodejs project on server shearing with cpanel and now it runs smoothly.

I use pm2 service for running file in background but if server get restarted the daemon won't be started automatically and should be started manually. I want to run the daemon even the server get rebooted.

Comment: Check the documentation here for a tutorial: https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/startup/